# Summing values of an array that are corresponded to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve the following issue in javascript, have tried different ways of implementing it but with no real success so far. I have 2 arrays of the same length, for example:

```
var years=[2010,2011,2009,2008,2010,2011,2007,2008,2008]
var money=[2,3,6,5,13,8,3,9,7]
```

The index of each element of `money` is connected to the same index element of `years` in terms of some money spent that year. I would like my program to construct a new array of distinct years (removing the same values of the `years` array) and a new money array with elements the summation of the initial money array values corresponding to each year.

```
years_new=[2010,2011,2009,2008,2007]
money_new=[2+13,3+8,6,5+9+7,3]
```

How would I go about doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This may be the answer:

```
var years=[2010,2011,2009,2008,2010,2011,2007,2008,2008];
var money=[2,3,6,5,13,8,3,9,7];

fixed_years = Array();
for(var i=0; i < years.length; i++){
    console.log(fixed_years[years[i]]);
    if(fixed_years[years[i]]){
       fixed_years[years[i]] += money[i]; 
    }else{
        fixed_years[years[i]] = money[i];
    }

}
console.log(fixed_years);

new_years = Array();
new_money = Array();
for(year in fixed_years){
    new_years.push(year);
    new_money.push(fixed_years[year]);
}
console.log(new_money);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary object for keeping the counted values.

```js
var years = [2010, 2011, 2009, 2008, 2010, 2011, 2007, 2008, 2008],
    money = [2, 3, 6, 5, 13, 8, 3, 9, 7],
    count = {}, i = 0,
    years_new = [],
    money_new = [];

while (i < years.length && i < money.length) {
    count[years[i]] = (count[years[i]] || 0) + money[i];
    i++;
}
years_new = Object.keys(count);
money_new = years_new.map(function (a) { return count[a]; });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(years_new, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(money_new, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or count without any temporary storage. This solution maintains the order of the original `years` array.

```js
var years = [2010, 2011, 2009, 2008, 2010, 2011, 2007, 2008, 2008],
    money = [2, 3, 6, 5, 13, 8, 3, 9, 7],
    i = 0, p,
    years_new = [],
    money_new = [];

while (i < years.length && i < money.length) {
    p = years_new.indexOf(years[i]);
    if (~p) {
        money_new[p] += money[i];
    } else {
        years_new.push(years[i]);
        money_new.push(money[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(years_new, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(money_new, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

A third proposal which reduces both arrays if the index of `years` is not equal of the `Array.prototype.indexOf`. Then it splices both arrays and add the spliced value.

```js
var years = [2010, 2011, 2009, 2008, 2010, 2011, 2007, 2008, 2008],
    money = [2, 3, 6, 5, 13, 8, 3, 9, 7],
    i = years.length, p,
    years_new = years,
    money_new = money;

while (i--) {
    p = years_new.indexOf(years_new[i]);
    if (p !== i) {
        years_new.splice(i, 1);
        money_new[p] += +money_new.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(years_new, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(money_new, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object by using the `Array.prototype.reduce` method. The object keys are years and their value are the sum of the corresponding *money* array elements.

```
var ret = years.reduce(function(ret, el, i) {
    ret[el] = (ret[el] || 0) + money[i];
    return ret;
}, {});
```

For getting all the years you can use the `Object.keys` method:

```
var years_new = Object.keys(ret);
var money_new = years_new.map(function(el) { return ret[el] });
```

Comment: Note the order of `years_new` is not guaranteed, so the result might be a permutation of `[2010,2011,2009,2008,2007]`. `money_new` will be correctly associated to that order, though.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, that's completely true. It should also be noted that although order of JavaScript objects is undefined, Chrome/Chromium does sort the objects, so the `years_new` should be a sorted array on those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, using the following helpers (note that any other `uniq` would work, as this one is not intended to be efficient).

**Helpers.**

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function() {
  return this.reduce(function(sofar, cur) {
    return sofar.indexOf(cur) < 0 ? sofar.concat([cur]) : sofar;
  }, []);
};

Array.prototype.indicesOf = function(el) {
  return this.reduce(function(indices, cur, i) {
    return (cur === el) ? indices.concat(i) : indices;
  }, []);
};
```

**Usage.**

Now the task of selecting the new years is a simple call to `uniq`:

```
var years_new = years.uniq();
```

And to map the old `money` into the required one, we accumulate the old `years` and use each index to get the sum of the old `money`:

```
var money_new = years_new.map(function(ny) {
  return years.indicesOf(ny).reduce(function(sum, index) {
    return sum + money[index];
  }, 0);
});
```